# Markov Chains - Strong Markov Property

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I'm struck with an exercise. I tried, but the results don't seem to fit to those proposed.

**Exercise:**
Two players play the following game. The one who begins draws two cards from a deck of 40 cards (10 cards per suit):

- if they are both clubs the player wins;
- if they are of the same suit but not clubs, the player shuffles the cards and start again;
- else the player shuffles the cards and let the other player play.

1) Model the game with a Markov Chain.

2) What is the probability that who started wins?

**My attempt**:
If $X_n$ is the player in the current turn, we have a three state MC whose state space is $\{A,\, B,\, \text{exit}\}$. The *exit* state is the one reached when the game ends.
The transition matrix is

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}9/52 & 10/13 & 3/52 \\ 10/13 & 9/52 & 3/52 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

since the probability of staying is $\frac{3 \cdot 9}{4 \cdot 39}$ and so on.

For the second question I thought I could use the Strong Markov Property (the one which states that a Markov Chain can start afresh in a Stopping Time) by using the last time I see A (or B) before the game ends. Starting from that point, the probability is just the jump from A (or B) to exit times two (to consider both the A and the B case).

What's wrong with this last point?

Comment: $40$ cards or $52$?

Comment: 40. It's an Italian deck :)

Comment: Would you, please, explain the meaning of the states $A,B,exit$?

Comment: @zoli A is the first player, B is the second one and exit is an absorbing state such that when you reach it the game ends. The chain is a sequence of A and B till the exit which is the last state

Comment: I only read this quick but usually, the ``last time A happens before B'' types of variables are **not** stopping times. Edit : the time variable you take is definitely not a stopping time

Comment: @hHhh I am not sure I got it. Is it because the time _T_ I choose depends on $X_{T+1}$ as well?

Comment: @Phugo intuitively a stopping time is a time at which you can stop **knowing only the past and present**. In your case you need to know what happens after $T$ to determine the value of $T$. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time

Comment: Ok, I understood. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

First, I wouldn't modelise the markov chain like that , I would consider four states 1 = "player A play", 2 = "player B play", 3 = "player A had won" and 4 = "player B had won"

The transition matrix would be

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 
9/52 & 10/13 & 3/52 & 0 \\
10/13 & 9/52 & 0 & 3/52 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then the probability to be at each state after n step knowing that we started in state 1) is given by

$$\pi^{(n)} = (1,0,0,0)M^n$$

And the probability we're looking for is

$$p = \lim_{n\to +\infty} \pi_3^{(n)}$$

To calculate $M^n$, you can diagonalize it, and it should give you the answer (I didn't do the calcul)

Comment: Thank you! It's more or less the same procedure outlined in my handout, but I was really interested in understanding why the method I proposed is not alright. Probably I didn't understand what's the Markov Property is about and I want to know where I have been wrong.
Thank you, again :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve question 2 you don't need Markov chains, only first step analysis.
In the first step there are 3 possibilities:

1. player $A$ wins,
2. the game starts over,
3. the deck goes to player $B$.

Letting $p_A$ be the probability 
that player $A$ is the eventual winner, and taking these 3 cases into account gives equation (1) below.

With $p={10\choose 2}/{40\choose 2}$ we get 
$$p_A=p\cdot 1 +3p\cdot p_A+(1-4p)\cdot(1-p_A).\tag 1$$
Solving (1) gives $p_A={43\over 83}=  0.51808$.